# python: efficiency in a problem involving power series

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, performance, generator

**Problem definition:**

This is a problem from [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reversed-self-power/).

Define a *self reversed power sequence*, S, as:

```
S(0) = 0
S(1) = 1
S(2) = 1^2 + 2 = 3
S(3) = 1^3 + 2^2 + 3 = 8
...
S(n) = 1^n + 2^(n-1) + ... + (n-1)^2 + n
```

Implement a function which takes 2 arguments (num_dig and ord_max), and finds the smallest number of the sequence less than num dig which also has ord_max number of digits.

If there is a number with correct amount of digits, the result should be an array in the form:

```
[True, smallest found term] 

[False, -1]
```

These are some examples:

```
n-th Term    Term Value
1              0
2              1
3              3
4              8
5              22
6              65
7              209
8              732
9              2780
10             11377
11             49863
12             232768
13             1151914
14             6018785
```

So sample tests include:

```
min_length_num(5, 10) == [True, 10]   # 10th term has 5 digits
min_length_num(7, 11) == [False, -1]  # no terms before 13th has 7 digits
min_length_num(7, 14) == [True, 13]   # 13th term already has 7 digits
```

**My approach**:

I create a generator that yields all the values of the power series S up to a value n:

```
def seq(n):
    for i in range(n):
        s = range(i+1)
        j = i+1
        tot = 0
        while j > 0:
            for k in s:
                tot += k**j
                j -=1
            break
        yield tot
```

then I check the values of the generators and: either return True as soon as I encounter the first value with the desired number of digits, or return False otherwise:

```
def min_length_num(num_dig, ord_max): 
    i = 1
    for n in seq(ord_max):
        if len(str(n)) == num_dig:
            return [True, i]
        elif len(str(n)) > num_dig:
            break
        i +=1
    return [False, -1]
```

This passes all the tests but does not complete the test process as it times out. The input range assumes ord_max <= 1000.

I am not very proficient with generators so maybe I am doing something wrong there, or doing it not appropriately. I'd appreciate some help. Thank you.

**EDIT: another solution.**

Since I know ord_max <= 1000, I could just pre-compute all the values and modify the code as follows:

```
p = [n for n in seq(1000)]

def min_length_num(num_dig, ord_max): 
    i = 1
    for k in p[:ord_max]:
        if len(str(k)) == num_dig:
            return [True, i]
        elif len(str(k)) > num_dig:
            break
        i +=1
    return [False, -1]
```

This is faster and solves my problem, but I find it a quite ugly solution, more of a dirty hack. I'd like to have something better.

Comment: Use `pow` not `**`. The former uses exponentiation by squaring which is an order of magnitude faster than naive multiplication.

Comment: Thanks @Rishav I didn't know that. However, I don't think that solves the issue.

Comment: @Rishav: are you sure they're different? In CPython at least they both use the same underlying code for computing x to the power of y (specifically [`long_pow`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/53ebf4b0709f431b7262aa5daccef7eafde7383e/Objects/longobject.c#L4118))

Answer (score 1):

Not full solution but some optimization tips:

You don't need to calculate all powers of natural numbers again and again - I suspect exponentiation is rather long operation. Instead store list of current powers and multiply `power[k]` by `k`  at every step

```
 1  4  3       //3rd stage
 1  8  9  4    //4th stage
```

and update sum value with difference between old and new power

```
 S(4) = S(3) + (8-4) + (9-3) + 4 = 22
```

Also precalculate goal value with needed number of digits

```
  powten = 10**(num_dig-1)  //1 000 000 for num_dig=7
```

and compare sums with `powten` without conversion into string

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was editing my question (I found a "dirty solution"). I like the first thing you suggest, I have to think about how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Mbo's suggestion, but instead of updating the sequences with differences between old and new power, you can simply multiply the existing sequence with corresponding increments, and append the new term number (minus one, since the first term's value is 0) to the sequence:

```
def min_length_num(dig, max_term):
    seq = []
    target = pow(10, dig - 1)
    term = 1
    while term <= max_term:
        for i in range(term - 1):
            seq[i] *= i
        seq.append(term - 1)
        if sum(seq) >= target:
            return [True, term]
        term += 1
    return [False, -1]
```

so that:

```
print(min_length_num(5, 10))
print(min_length_num(7, 11))
print(min_length_num(7, 14))
```

would output:

```
[True, 10]
[False, -1]
[True, 13]
```